# Send push-notification using WebSockets after button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, websocket

I'm very close to implementing a system in C# which allows me to send a push-notification with the click of a button from an interface written in ASP.net to a C# console application acting as client. This all using WebSockets.

After reading a lot of tutorials and reusing code found online I'm already able to successfully establish a WebSocket connection. I'm yet not able to actually send a Notification.

The part I'm struggling with is the function that get's triggered as soon as a button is clicked:

```
//Close ticket and send push-notification over websocket
public void Close(int id) {
    //Ticket ticket = mgr.GetTicket(id);

    //Create a new notification
    Notification notif = new Notification();
    notif.message = "Rofl test123 Notification lol";

    //Initialize WebSocketMiddleware here??
    //WebSocketsMiddleware wsm = new WebSocketsMiddleware(what parameter??);
    //wsm.Invoke(what HttpContext parameter???)

    NotificationManager notifMgr;
    //notifMgr.AddSubscriber(wsm);
    //notifMgr.SendNotificationAsync(notif);


    return;
}
```

The specific questions/problems I'm encountering are:

1. How to initialize the class WebSocketsMiddleware? Does it need to be initialized, if yes, what is the parameter with type RequestDelegate? What do I pass to that parameter?
2. WebSocketsMiddleware has an Invoke function with parameter context of type HttpContext. Do I just need to pass `new HttpContext()` to this? Is that sufficient?
3. Someone made a class NotificationManager, this class uses the middleware to actually send a notification. Do I just need to pass the initialized WebSocketsMiddleware variable as parameter for NotificationManager.AddSubscriber()? Will the notifications of each client be nicely separated then?
4. Can I after that just use SendNotificationAsync() to send the notification?
5. Bonus question: Say that each client has it's own button. When I click a client's button only that client may receive a push-notification. How to make sure that all the other client's don't receive the same notification as well?

To be able to help me with these questions you'll need the following classes. The question is merely about WebSockets but more about how to initiate and use the classes I gathered from the tutorials.

**Notification.cs - Class representing a Notification (notification text, send-date,...):**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SC.UI.MVC.Models
{
    public class Notification
    {
        public Guid? notificationId { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }
        public DateTime timestamp { get; set; }
        public string message { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }

        public Notification()
        {
            // add a new guid as a unique identifier for the notification in the db
            notificationId = Guid.NewGuid();
        }
    }
}
```

**WebSocketsMiddleware.cs - Has the low-level part of the WebSockets handled, invoking connection etc:**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.WebSockets;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace NotificationsApi.Notifications
{
    public class WebSocketsMiddleware
    {
        // private variable to track the next delegate to call in the request chain
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public WebSocketsMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            CancellationToken ct = context.RequestAborted;
            string currentSubscriberId = null;
            WebSocket currentSocket = null;

            // we want to listen on a specific path for websocket communications
            if (context.Request.Path == "/notifications/ws")
            {
                // make sure the request is a websocket request
                if (context.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest)
                {
                    currentSocket = await context.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync();
                    currentSubscriberId = NotificationManager.Instance.AddSubscriber(currentSocket);

                    // keep the socket open until we get a cancellation request
                    while (true)
                    {
                        if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else // return an HTTP bad request status code if anything other a web socket request is made on this URI
                { 
                    context.Response.StatusCode = 400;
                }
            }

            // clean up the socket
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(currentSubscriberId))
            {
                NotificationManager.Instance.RemoveSubscriber(currentSubscriberId);
                if (currentSocket != null)
                {
                    await currentSocket.CloseOutputAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, "Closing", CancellationToken.None);
                    currentSocket.Dispose();
                }
            }

            // call the next delegate in the pipeline
            await _next(context);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

**NotificationManager.cs - Interface/Class with three functions to add and remove subscribers, and to actually send a notification. Uses the WebSocket middleware to achieve this:**

```
using SC.UI.MVC.Models;
//using NotificationsApi.Persistence;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.WebSockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace NotificationsApi.Notifications
{
    // interface for NotificationManager for dependency injection
    public interface INotificationManager
    {
        string AddSubscriber(WebSocket subscriber);
        void RemoveSubscriber(string subscriberId);
        Task SendNotificationAsync(Notification notification);
    }

    public class NotificationManager : INotificationManager 
    {
        // static instance of the NotificationManager class
        private static INotificationManager _instance;
        public static INotificationManager Instance { get { return _instance ?? (_instance = new NotificationManager()); } set { _instance = value; } }

        // static dictionary to keep track of all notification subscribers
        private static ConcurrentDictionary<string, WebSocket> _subscribers = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, WebSocket>();

        // adds a subscriber to receive notifications
        public string AddSubscriber(WebSocket subscriber)
        {
            var subscriberId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            _subscribers.TryAdd(subscriberId, subscriber);
            return subscriberId.ToString();
        }

        // removes a notifications subscriber
        public void RemoveSubscriber(string subscriberId)
        {
            WebSocket empty;
            _subscribers.TryRemove(subscriberId, out empty);
        }

        // sends a notification to all subscribers
        public async Task SendNotificationAsync(Notification notification)
        {
            // add the notification to the persistence store
            //await PersistenceManager.Instance.AddNotificationAsync(notification);

            // send the notification to all subscribers
            foreach (var s in _subscribers)
            {
                if (s.Value.State == WebSocketState.Open)
                {
                    var jsonNotification = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(notification);
                    await SendStringAsync(s.Value, jsonNotification);
                }
            }
        }

        // sends a string via web socket communication
        private async Task SendStringAsync(WebSocket socket, string data, CancellationToken ct = default(CancellationToken))
        {
            var buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
            var segment = new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer);
            await socket.SendAsync(segment, WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, ct);
        }
    }
}
```

**Client.cs - Client receiving the push-notification. Not really a problem here I guess:**

```
    /* WEBSOCKET PART */
    //Variables for websocket
    private static object consoleLock = new object();
    private const int sendChunkSize = 256;
    private const int receiveChunkSize = 256;
    private const bool verbose = true;
    private static readonly TimeSpan delay = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(30000);

    //Function to check if a ticket from this client is closed/solved
    public void checkTicketSolved() {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Connect("ws://localhost:5050/notifications/ws").Wait();
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
    }

    public static async Task Connect(string uri)
    {
        ClientWebSocket webSocket = null;

        try
        {
            webSocket = new ClientWebSocket();
            await webSocket.ConnectAsync(new Uri(uri), CancellationToken.None);
            await Task.WhenAll(Receive(webSocket), Send(webSocket));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (webSocket != null)
                webSocket.Dispose();
            Console.WriteLine();

            lock (consoleLock)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine("WebSocket closed.");
                Console.ResetColor();
            }
        }
    }
   static UTF8Encoding encoder = new UTF8Encoding();

    private static async Task Send(ClientWebSocket webSocket)
    {

        //byte[] buffer = encoder.GetBytes("{\"op\":\"blocks_sub\"}"); //"{\"op\":\"unconfirmed_sub\"}");
        byte[] buffer = encoder.GetBytes("{\"op\":\"unconfirmed_sub\"}");
        await webSocket.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None);

      while (webSocket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
        {
            LogStatus(false, buffer, buffer.Length);
            await Task.Delay(delay);
        }
    }

    private static async Task Receive(ClientWebSocket webSocket)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[receiveChunkSize];
        while (webSocket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
        {
            var result = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);
            if (result.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Close)
            {
                await webSocket.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, string.Empty, CancellationToken.None);
            }
            else
            {
                LogStatus(true, buffer, result.Count);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void LogStatus(bool receiving, byte[] buffer, int length)
    {
        lock (consoleLock)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = receiving ? ConsoleColor.Green : ConsoleColor.Gray;
            //Console.WriteLine("{0} ", receiving ? "Received" : "Sent");

            if (verbose)
                Console.WriteLine(encoder.GetString(buffer));

            Console.ResetColor();
        }
    }
}
```

You can also find this code on [Github](https://gitlab.com/NielD/finalhelp).
The relevant parts of the code are located in:

- WebServer/UI-MVC/Controllers/TicketController.cs -> Contains function triggered when a button is clicked.
- WebServer/UI-MVC/Notifications -> Contains NotificationManager.cs and WebSocketsMiddleware.cs
- WebServer/UI-MVC/Models -> Contains Notification.cs
- Client/ contains all the code for the client's console application

To give you some context about the application:
This application represents a ticketing system which allows clients/customers which use my software to open support tickets. The WebServer-part is for administrators/employees of me to answer and manage tickets. The Console Application is what my customers/clients need to have installed in order to contact my support service and open a support ticket. When an administrator closes the ticket of a client by clicking a button, it means the ticket and thus the client's problem was resolved and closed. Resulting in the client getting a push-notification about that.

I am not looking for references to other tutorials about WebSockets or suggestions using SignalR instead or whatever, I've already read all of them and I've already used SignalR but am interested in pure WebSockets now. I would be very grateful for someone who could help me working out the first part of code posted in this question (the Close-function) and explains what he has done. Thanks!

Comment: It's for educational purposes. We have to investigate some specific technologies and implement them. I have chosen SignalR and Websockets. I have to use them both, already implemented SignalR with success. Now getting close with WebSockets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution myself.

First I made a new controller called **NotificationsController.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using SC.UI.MVC.Models;
using NotificationsApi.Notifications;
//using NotificationsApi.Persistence;
using System.Net.Http;

// For more information on enabling Web API for empty projects, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=397860

namespace NotificationsApi.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/notifications")]
    public class NotificationsController : Controller
    {
        // GET api/notifications
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Get()
        {
            try
            {
                var notifications = new List<Notification>();
                //notifications = PersistenceManager.Instance.GetNotifications();
                return Ok(notifications);
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                // log exception
                // TODO: implement logging

                // return a 500
                return StatusCode(500);
            }
        }

        // POST api/notifications
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Post(string message)
        {

            Notification notification = new Notification();
            notification.message = message;

            Console.WriteLine(message);

            try
            {
                // return a 400 if we didn't get a valid json payload in the body
                if (notification == null)
                    return BadRequest();

                await NotificationManager.Instance.SendNotificationAsync(notification);

                // we aren't returning the object to reference because POSTing a notification is fire and forget
                return Created(string.Empty, null);
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                // log the error
                // TODO: implement logging

                // return a 500
                return StatusCode(500);
            }

            return Ok();
        }
    }
}
```

Then I commented out the unnecessary properties in Notification.cs so only Guid and message remain. Now I'm able to just send a notification by calling the NotificationsController with a POST request carrying the message-parameter as data.